# How to run activator?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, typesafe-activator

I have java-8, play-2.2.6 and activator-1.3.5-minimal.

I created scala application then it's throw some exception. I can't understand.

I need any project migration, this is all the latest version.

Please help me, thanks in advance

```
C:\Sample\play\newsacla-app>play clean compile eclipse
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256M; sup
port was removed in 8.0
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.0 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
        confs: [default]
        43 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (12440kB/1035ms)
[info] Loading project definition from C:\Sample\play\newsacla-app\project
[warn]  [FAILED     ] com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.6!sbt-plugin.jar: Connect
ion timed out: connect (22877ms)
[warn]  [FAILED     ] com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.6!sbt-plugin.jar: Connect
ion timed out: connect (22877ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-pl
ugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.2.6/jars/sbt-plugin.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.6!sbt-plugin.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.2.6!sbt-pl
ugin.jar
        at sbt.IvyActions$.sbt$IvyActions$$resolve(IvyActions.scala:213)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:122)
        at sbt.IvyActions$$anonfun$update$1.apply(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module$$anonfun$withModule$1.apply(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anonfun$withIvy$1.apply(Ivy.scala:104)
        at sbt.IvySbt.sbt$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:51)
        at sbt.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:60)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:98)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRet
ries$1(Locks.scala:81)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:
102)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:11)
        at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:10)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:62)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:52)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
        at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:60)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:101)
        at sbt.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:97)
        at sbt.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:116)
        at sbt.IvyActions$.update(IvyActions.scala:121)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1144)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$sbt$Classpaths$$work$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala
:1142)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1
165)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1$$anonfun$73.apply(Defaults.scala:1
163)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$lastOutput$1.apply(Tracked.scala:35)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1167)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$doWork$1$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1162)
        at sbt.Tracked$$anonfun$inputChanged$1.apply(Tracked.scala:45)
        at sbt.Classpaths$.cachedUpdate(Defaults.scala:1170)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1135)
        at sbt.Classpaths$$anonfun$updateTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:1113)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:23
7)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestric
tions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: download failed: com.typesafe.play#sbt-
plugin;2.2.6!sbt-plugin.jar
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

Comment: It seems as if you cannot download the `sbt-plugin.jar`. Could you check that it is available in the specified repositories?

Comment: yes, check it out, that "sbt.plugin.jar" file is there.

Comment: Also the version `2.2.6`?

Comment: yes, there is same version. please check it out http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/2.2.6/jars/